# Caffe2's equivalent to Caffe's Net.backward()?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe, caffe2

I am trying to obtain the gradient of the loss **with respect to an input image**. In Caffe (the original), the following code achieved my goal:

```
### Load image into net's data layer
img = caffe.io.load_image(jpg_file)
transformed_image = transformer.preprocess('data', img)
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformed_image    # copy image data into memory for net

...

### Form the final label vector (one hot vector)
finalLabelVector = np.zeros((1,num_classes))
finalLabelVector[0,ground_truth_label] = 1

### Do a backward pass using finalLabelVector
# must have 'force_backward: true' set in deploy prototxt
backwardpassData = net.backward(**{net.outputs[0]: finalLabelVector})

# Get the derivative with respect to the input (data layer)
delta = backwardpassData['data']
```

What must I do using the Caffe2 Python interface to calculate the same `delta` as above?